# How to find control in gridview using find control method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview,in which there is item template..in this template there is a control.I need to find this control using find control method.
How can i achieve this

Comment: Did you try _anything_?

Comment: Maybe with .... `FindControl`?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridViewName.Rows) 
{
    if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
    {
        Control myControl = row.FindControl("ControlID") as Control;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)grdInbox.Rows[0].Controls[5].FindControl("chkDelete");
```